# Passing parameters to save()

Tags: ember-data

Is it possible to pass parameters like this?  I need to pass some information that is not part of the model itself.

```
myModel.save({site : 23})
```

Comment: Where does site come from? Is it metadata? Is it edited on the controller? How come it's not defined on the model

Comment: @IgorT the site represents the previous site belonging to the model.  I have other reasons for this also,  I use a java/spring backend and passing params allows me to differentiate between target save method.

Comment: @IgorT I have the same needs: some contextual params are needed by the backend...

Comment: @IgorT I just submitted a PR to address this need: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2310 :-)

Comment: @jax Please see this comment on my PR: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2310#issuecomment-57150613, there is a way to do it in a standard way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible if you:

- add a 'volatile' attribute to your model,
- define a custom model serializer, and override its `serializeIntoHash` method.

For instance:

```js
App.Model = DS.Model.extend({
  //...
  site: DS.attr('number', { serialize: false })
});
```

```js
App.ModelSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    this._super(hash, type, record, options);

    Ember.merge(hash, {
      'site': record.get('site')
    });
  }
});
```

See this [comment](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2310#issuecomment-57137305), this is the correct way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 19):

[You can pass options as of Ember Data 2.2](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3278). However, you have to remember to pass your options under the `adapterOptions` property. For example,

```
myModel.save({
  adapterOptions: {
    site: 23
  }
});
```

Inside either of `DS.Store#findAll`, `DS.Store#findRecord`, `DS.Store#query`, `DS.Model#save` and `DS.Model#destroyRecord`, one of the parameters should now have `adapterOptions`. In the case of `DS.Model#save`, you can override `updateRecord` in your adapter:

```
export default DS.Adapter.extend({
  updateRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
    // will now have `snapshot.adapterOptions`.
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks